# How to import function from another file?

Tags: python, importerror

I recently started learning Python and I am in a bit of a pickle right now.
There are three files.

First file. `main.py`:

```
#the morse code
from MorseCode import*
from Check import product, Check_For_Alphas
Word1 = input("Enter the text") #text enter
Word = Word1.lower()
#print(Word)
Sentence_splited = list(Word) #the sentence is splited here in the form of a list
#print(Sentence_splited)
length = len(Sentence_splited)
#print(len(Sentence_splited),"elements") #used len() meathod to give length
count = 0 #this is for the loop

while count < length:
    #checks for the alphsbets needs improvement
    Check_For_Alphas()
    count = count+1
print(*product)#gives the morse code
```

And the second file

```
from Main_Program import Sentence_splited, count, length
from MorseCode import *

product = []
def Check_For_Alphas():
    if (Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'a'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['a'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'b'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['b'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'c'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['c'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'd'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['d'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'e'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['e'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'f'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['f'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'g'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['g'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'h'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['h'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'i'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['i'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'j'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['j'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'k'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['k'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'l'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['l'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'm'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['m'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'n'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['n'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'o'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['o'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'p'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['p'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'q'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['q'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'r'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['r'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 's'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['s'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 't'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['t'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'u'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['u'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'v'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['v'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'w'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['w'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'x'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['x'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'y'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['y'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'z'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['z'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == ' '):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha[' '])
```

here you just have to look at the first 5 to 6 lines the rest I checked.
And here is the third file

```
CodeForAlpha = {
    "a": "._",
    "b": "_...",
    "c": "_._.",
    "d": "_..",
    "e": ".",
    "f": ".._.",
    "h": "....",
    "i": "..",
    "j": "._ _ _",
    "k": "_._",
    "l": "._..",
    "m": "_ _",
    "n": "_.",
    "o": "_ _ _",
    "p": "._ _.",
    "q": "_ _._",
    "r": "._.",
    "s": "...",
    "t": "_",
    "u": ".._",
    "v": "..._",
    "w": "._ _",
    "x": "_.._",
    "y": "_._ _",
    "z": "_ _..",
    " ": " "
}
```

I am unable to use the program.
The error is:

````
  File "d:/download/JAVA PROJECT/Python_Project/Dict_Prototype/Main_Program.py", line 3, in <module>
    import Check
  File "d:\download\JAVA PROJECT\Python_Project\Dict_Prototype\Check.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Main_Program import Sentence_splited, count, length
  File "d:\download\JAVA PROJECT\Python_Project\Dict_Prototype\Main_Program.py", line 15, in <module>
    Check_For_Alphas()
NameError: name 'Check_For_Alphas' is not defined
```
````

Comment: Could you show the file paths ? And also, you wrote a really complicated code with these `if`statements.

Comment: You have an import loop there.  `Main_Program` imports `Check` which imports `Main_Program`.  You should NOT be importing `Main_Program` inside `Check`.  You should pass to the function everything it needs as parameters.

Comment: You have cyclic imports in your code which is causing the problem. Easiest way to fix this would be to give the function `Check_for_alphas` parameters: `Check_for_Alphas(sentence_splited, length, count)` so you would not have to import those from your main file

Comment: How can I import the dictionary that way?

Comment: The dictionary is not part of the circular import.  It is self-contained.  Keep doing that the same way you are.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a cross module import. The origin of problem is how Python works with imports. When you write constructions like `from module import *` or `from module import func1, func2` then the module file gets executed.

Here you've got `from Main_Program import Sentence_splited, count, length` in the second file (which I assume is called `Check.py`) so it starts to run `Main_program.py` where you've got `import from Check import product, Check_For_Alphas` but `Check.py` was not initialized to the end as we are still only on line 2. That's why you are getting NameError.
To fix this you can import modules only in functions you actually use them or import them via `import module` as in that case `module` will be executed only on first use of it (lazy loading of modules)

From the previous text if you write files like this:

**Main_program.py**

```py
#the morse code
from MorseCode import*
import Check
Word1 = input("Enter the text")#text enter
Word = Word1.lower()
#print(Word)
Sentence_splited = list(Word)#the sentence is splited here in the form of a list
#print(Sentence_splited)
length = len(Sentence_splited)
#print(len(Sentence_splited),"elements")      #used len() meathod to give length
count = 0#this is for the loop

while count < length:
    #checks for the alphsbets needs improvement
    Check.Check_For_Alphas()
    count = count+1
print(*Check.product)#gives the morse code
```

**Check.py**

```py
from MorseCode import *

product = []
def Check_For_Alphas():
    from Main_Program import Sentence_splited, count, length
    if (Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'a'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['a'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'b'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['b'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'c'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['c'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'd'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['d'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'e'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['e'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'f'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['f'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'g'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['g'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'h'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['h'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'i'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['i'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'j'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['j'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'k'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['k'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'l'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['l'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'm'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['m'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'n'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['n'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'o'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['o'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'p'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['p'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'q'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['q'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'r'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['r'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 's'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['s'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 't'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['t'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'u'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['u'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'v'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['v'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'w'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['w'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'x'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['x'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'y'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['y'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == 'z'):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha['z'])
    elif(Sentence_splited[length-(length-count)] == ' '):
        product.append(CodeForAlpha[' '])
```

then you'll initialize files correctly without any circular dependencies with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Make your main loop:

```
product = []
for c in Sentence_splited:
    product.append( Check_For_Alphas(c))
print(*product)
```

And replace the entire Check.py with this:

```
from MorseCode import *

def Check_For_Alphas(ch):
    if ch in CodeForAlpha:
        return CodeForAlpha[ch]
    return 'xxx'
```

Comment: Hello, I just want to know that why the return has only 'xxx' like is it the space where i need to fill something?

Comment: If the character is in your list, we return the Morse.  Otherwise, it's a character we don't know, and we return 'xxx'.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need all the imports?
Be careful not to import in a loop, if you do.

Consider this single-file solution, especially the `morse_encode` function.
You do not need all those checks, as you already have the dictionary set up.

```py
from typing import List


CodeForAlpha = {
    "a": "._",
    "b": "_...",
    "c": "_._.",
    "d": "_..",
    "e": ".",
    "f": ".._.",
    "h": "....",
    "i": "..",
    "j": "._ _ _",
    "k": "_._",
    "l": "._..",
    "m": "_ _",
    "n": "_.",
    "o": "_ _ _",
    "p": "._ _.",
    "q": "_ _._",
    "r": "._.",
    "s": "...",
    "t": "_",
    "u": ".._",
    "v": "..._",
    "w": "._ _",
    "x": "_.._",
    "y": "_._ _",
    "z": "_ _..",
    " ": " "
}


def validate_input(s: str) -> bool:
    l = s.split()
    for w in l:
        if not w.isalpha():
            return False
    return True


def get_user_input() -> str:
    while True:
        text = input("Enter the text:\n")
        if validate_input(text):
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid input, only alphabetic characters and spaces are allowd.")
            print("Try again, please!")
    return text


def morse_encode(text: str) -> List[str]:
    result = list()
    for char in text.lower():
        result.add(CodeForAlpha[char])
    return result


"""
Less verbose version:
def morse_encode(text: str) -> List[str]:
    return [CodeForAlpha[char] for char in text.lower()]
"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_text = get_user_input()
    morse_code_list = morse_encode(user_text)
    print(morse_code_list)
```

Comment: Hi, I was unable to use the dict properly, that's the reason why i did it like that thanks for helping but can you explain the last 5 lines of thr code?

Comment: The last if block `if __name__ == '__main__'` is something you should get used to. It only runs, if you directly run the file, not if you import the file. So if you import the file you can use the defined functions and the dictionary, yet these lines will not run. I hope that clarifies.